# How to add a image to a Table Cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to add my pdf image to the end of my tabelCell's text

This is for my Table, I would like the image to somehow be concatenated after the text ends

```
<TableCell component="th" scope="row" className = {classes.tableCell} >
  PDF example download <div img src="static/image/file-pdf.png"/>
</TableCell>

I would expext that this image would be placed next to the text but this isnt the case.
```

Comment: Which module are you using?

Comment: why you have used div and img element common opening and closing of both like this not possible

Answer (score 1):

```
 <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className = {classes.tableCell} >
   PDF example download 
  <div>
    <img src="static/image/file-pdf.png"/>
   </div>
 </TableCell>
```